# passing variable back from php to jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to convert my login page to use html and use jquery and php to fetch and process the results, Reason is if i want to go mobile with my project then i am nearly there.

The problem i have is passing variables back from php to jquery to display at the same time.

my example
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Auth Demo 2</title>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="handleLogin()">

        <form id="loginForm">

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="email" />



            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />


        <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submitButton">
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
    function handleLogin(){

        var form = $("#loginForm");
        var u = $("#email", form).val();
        var p = $("#password", form).val();

        if(u!= '' && p!= '') {
             $.post("http://www.mysite.co.uk/login.php",{ 
                        email:$('#email', form).val(),
                        password:$('#password', form).val(),
                        rand:Math.random() 
                      } ,function(data)
                          {
                             if(data=='yes') //if correct login detail
                             {
                                 alert( "Request success: ");
                             }
                             else
                             {  
                                  //add reason in alert box here
                                  alert ("failed reason")
                              }
                   });
        } else {
                    alert( "Username/password empty");
               }
         return false;//not to post the  form physically

     }
```

login.php

```
<?//get the posted values
require_once("../backend/functions.php");
dbconn(true);


if ($_POST["email"] && $_POST["password"]) {
    $password = passhash($_POST["password"]);

    if (!empty($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])) {
        $res = SQL_Query_exec("SELECT id, password, secret, status, enabled FROM users WHERE email = " . sqlesc($_POST["email"]) . "");
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

        if ( ! $row || $row["password"] != $password )
            $message = "Wrong password";
        elseif ($row["status"] == "pending")
            $message = "Account Pending";
        elseif ($row["enabled"] == "no")
            $message = "Account Suspened";
    } else
        $message = "No Username/password added";

    if (!$message){
        logincookie($row["id"], $row["password"], $row["secret"]);
        if (!empty($_POST["returnto"])) {
            header("Refresh: 0; url=" . $_POST["returnto"]);
            die();
        }
        else {
            echo  "yes";
            die();
        }
    }else{
        echo $message;
    }
}

logoutcookie();
```

As you can see when the login fails  have various reasons i want to pass back to the alert box. Whats the best way to go about this

Comment: it took me exactly 2 mins to format your answer(with wierd fromatting) .... and damn!! and i still see some extra space.. :(

Comment: you are not submitting form anywhere.

Comment: Sorry Bipen Will make sure its tidy next time

Comment: Jai - im submitting from the top index.html

Comment: no prbolem...... :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just alert data

```
  if(data=='yes') //if correct login detail
  {
      alert( "Request success: ");
  } 
  else{
        alert (data)
   }
```

however i recommmend to get the response as JSON.....

```
if(u!= '' && p!= '') {
     $.post("http://www.mysite.co.uk/login.php",{ 
               email:$('#email', form).val(),
               password:$('#password', form).val(),
               rand:Math.random() 
         } ,function(data)
             {
                if(data=='yes') //if correct login detail
                {
                    alert( "Request success: ");
                }
                else
                {                                                      //add reason in alert box here
                    alert (data)
                 }
           });

  } else {
         alert( "Username/password empty");
  }

     return false;//not to post the  form physically
  }
```

Comment: This does work thanks and i will look into json as you all have recommended it and im sure once i get a grasp of it. it will help me in the future ;)

Comment: welcome.. and have a look to JSON... it better to use that...  :):)... happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use JSON;

```
JSON.stringify(your_object, null, 2);
```

Catch the POST in PHP with this to get an array back: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$data = json_decode($_POST);
```

When PHP is done echo a encoded JSON string of your array data back: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
echo json_encode($return_data);
```

In jQuery, for testing do;

```
console.log(data);
console.log(data.yes);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use $.ajax() and use the "XML" type.  Then have login.php return a XML file with whatever parameters you need (user id, error message if any, username, etc).  You can then parse the XML file with jQuery to use those variables immediately.  It's more secure to handle errors on the backend anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
function handleLogin(){

    var form = $("#loginForm");
    var u = $("#email", form).val();
    var p = $("#password", form).val();

    if(u!= '' && p!= '') {

        jQuery.ajax({
             type: "POST", 
             url: "http://www.mysite.co.uk/login.php", 
             data: 'username='+u+'&password='+p+'&rand='+Math.random(),
             complete: function(data){

                 if(data.responseText == 'yes'){
                    alert( "Request success: ");
                 }else{
                    alert( "failed: ");
                 }

         });

    } else {

        alert( "Username/password empty"); 

    }

     return false;//not to post the  form physically

 }
```